# How to properly load integer value from .data section

Tags: assembly, arm

Logically, my code is functional. However, it only works when I manually set the register x1 to a value (such as 4) within the main function. If I try to use ldr x1,=targ, and I try testing the value by printing it out, I get -2147196624. Can anyone help me understand what's happening?

```
   .text
  .global main
  .extern printf
main:
    ldr x1,=targ  // set x1 to n
    mov x3,#0   // set x3 and x4
    mov x4,#1
    mov x5,#1   // set x5 (count = 1)
    bl fibo
    b done

fibo:
    mov x9, x3
    mov x3, x4
    add x4, x9, x4
    add x5, x5, #1
    cmp x5, x1
    ble fibo
    br x30

done:
    mov x1, x3
    ldr x0,=string
    bl printf

.data
    string:
        .asciz "%d\n"
    targ:
        .byte 4
.end
```

**Output**

The above code doesn't print anything, it gets trapped in an infinite loop in the fibo branch because the `ble fibo` condition is always met.

Comment: "Logically, my code is functional."  What does this mean in the context of multiple logic errors and issues?

Comment: And why haven't you fixed the errors pointed out with your previous question here?

Comment: @ErikEidt Well, I did fix it on my machine, but I didn't reflect that change in my post, but I updated it now. I believe it was just the one printing issue, and I qualified my statement by implying that a simple replacement of the line `ldr x1,=targ` with `mov x1,#4` prints the desired output.

Comment: @ErikEidt Do you have any contribution to my current problem?

Comment: Why did you tag this x86?

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica I'm sorry, I wasn't sure

Comment: What do the registers look like when after the `cmp` before the `ble`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ldr x1,=targ
```

means "address of" targ, not the value targ.  The instruction would need an addressing mode that could reach far so instead it uses a pc-relative addressing.

Just try it yourself.

```
.text 

    ldr x1,=targ
    nop
    nop
    
.data

targ:
    .byte 4

aarch64-none-elf-as so.s -o so.o
aarch64-none-elf-ld -Ttext=0x1000 -Tdata=0x2000 so.o -o so.elf
aarch64-none-elf-objdump -d so.elf


0000000000001000 <.text>:
    1000:   58000081    ldr x1, 1010 <__data_start-0xff0>
    1004:   d503201f    nop
    1008:   d503201f    nop
    100c:   00000000    
    1010:   00002000    .word   0x00002000
    1014:   00000000    .word   0x00000000
```

It is loading the address of the label.

```
aarch64-none-elf-objdump -D so.elf

so.elf:     file format elf64-littleaarch64


Disassembly of section .text:

0000000000001000 <.text>:
    1000:   58000081    ldr x1, 1010 <__data_start-0xff0>
    1004:   d503201f    nop
    1008:   d503201f    nop
    100c:   00000000
    1010:   00002000
    1014:   00000000

Disassembly of section .data:

0000000000002000 <__data_start>:
    2000:
```

so

```
.text 

    ldr x1,=targ
    ldr x1,[x1]
    nop
    nop
    nop
    
.data

targ:
    .byte 4



Disassembly of section .text:

0000000000001000 <.text>:
    1000:   580000c1    ldr x1, 1018 <__data_start-0xfe8>
    1004:   f9400021    ldr x1, [x1]
    1008:   d503201f    nop
    100c:   d503201f    nop
    1010:   d503201f    nop
    1014:   00000000    
    1018:   00002000    .word   0x00002000
    101c:   00000000    .word   0x00000000
```

but also you have the problem that ldr is not a byte load operation.

I am a bit rusty on my 64 bit arm.

```
.text 

    ldr x1,=targ
    ldrb w1,[x1]
    nop
    nop
    nop
    
.data

targ:
    .byte 4

0000000000001000 <.text>:
    1000:   580000c1    ldr x1, 1018 <__data_start-0xfe8>
    1004:   39400021    ldrb    w1, [x1]
    1008:   d503201f    nop
    100c:   d503201f    nop
    1010:   d503201f    nop
    1014:   00000000    
    1018:   00002000    .word   0x00002000
    101c:   00000000    .word   0x00000000
```

You can look this up in the arm documentation (no excuse for doing assembly language without the proper documentation. ARM architectural reference manual for armv8-a)

```
580000c1    ldr x1, 1018 <__data_start-0xfe8>

01011000000000....
```

LDR (literal) starts with a 0x011000,  so this is that instruction. (the 0x here means x is either 0 or 1 not a hex number, 0n011000)

```
0c1
000011000001
0000110 00001 immed 0x6 register x1

64-bit variant 
Applies when opc == 01 . (opc is bits 31:30)
LDR <Xt>, <label>

0x1018 - 0x1000 -0x18  00011000
110 00

4*6 = 24 = 0x18, 0x1000+0x18 = 0x1018.
```

So that offset is relative as one would expect it to be so this all makes sense.